# Лишний вывод в файл

Tags: c++, c, файлы

Вот у меня есть функция, которая создает файл размеров в 10 КБ

```
void CreateFile(string name)
{
    const unsigned int length = 10;
    char buff[1024];    
    fstream f;
    f.open(name, ios::binary | ios::out);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        f.write((char*)&buff, sizeof(buff));
    f.close();
}
```

И вот у меня есть функция, копирующая этот файл, а также возвращающая время копирования:

```
int First(string nameIn, string nameOut)
{
    unsigned int timeStart, timeStop;
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    char buff[1024];
    f1 = fopen(nameIn.c_str(), "r");
    f2 = fopen(nameOut.c_str(), "w");
    if (!f1 || !f2) return -1;  //если не удалось открыть
    rewind(f1);

    timeStart = clock();
    while (!feof(f1))  //проблема
    {
        fread(buff, 1024, 1, f1);
        fwrite(buff, 1024, 1, f2);
    }
    timeStop = clock();

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return timeStop - timeStart;
}
```

Но вот проблема: размер нового файла не 10 КБ, как ожидалось, а 11! 1 лишний раз записывает буфер. Проблема в условии цикла. Как заменить `feof()`? Или есть еще какие-нибудь решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 6):

[Тоскливо] Наверное, в сотый раз пишу здесь, что использовать

```
while (!feof(f1))
```

категорически нельзя, так как флаг конца файла устанавливается **после** неудачного чтения за концом файла. Этот 11-й раз - последний и неудачный - раз вы читаете, но ничего не считываете, и записываете в результате лишний блок...

Comment: если вы 100% уверены, что вопрос содержит именно эту проблему, то следует только один раз подробно ответить, а все остальные вопросы, которые сводятся к этой проблеме уже закрыть как дубликаты. У вас золотой знак по c++, одного вашего голоса достаточно, чтобы закрыть вопрос как дубликат -- не нужно в сотне мест одинаковые ответы писать (хотя бы потому, что если возникнет необходимость, то это затруднит обновление решения). [В тему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/685/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
while ( 1 )
    {
        fread(buff, 1024, 1, f1);
        if (feof(f1)) break;
        if (ferror(f1)) { /* Обработка ошибки*/ break;} 
        fwrite(buff, 1024, 1, f2);
    }
```

Comment: Проще `while(fread(buff,1024,1,f1)==1) fwrite(buff,1024,1,f2);`, а потом разбираться :) Если, конечно, файл состоит строго из 1024-байтных блоков... иначе лучше `fread(buff,1,1024,f1)` и смотреть, сколько именно считано...

Comment: Я постарался написать максимально ПРОСТО. Что бы TS понял идею.